# How can I check if a value is given for @Output() param in a parent component

Tags: angular

I'm writing a component, let's call it `DropDownComponent` which will be reused throughout my application and will have 7+ possible entries, each of which will run a different action in the Parent Component. Some of the options are not available in every place they run. What I'd like to do is in my instantiation only specify @Output handlers for the component, like this:

```
<drop-down-component
    (addHandler)="add($event)"
    (removeHandler)="remove($event)"></drop-down-component>
```

And then in my component:

```
export class DropDownComponent {
    @Output() addHandler: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() removeHandler: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() editHandler: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() renameHandler: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
    ...
```

In the child component I'd like to be able to see if `editHandler` and `renameHandler` are bound to anything, and if they aren't, just remove them from the template code using `*ngIf`, so I only see:

```
<drop-down>
    <div (click)="...">Add</div>
    <div (click)="...">Remove</div>
    <!-- ngIf'd by component <div (click)="...">Edit</div> -->
    <!-- ngIf'd by component <div (click)="...">Rename</div> -->
</drop-down>
```

This seems like it should be possible, but I haven't found any way to do it. It's obviously simple enough to just add a `[showAddOption]="true"` parameter to the parent's template, but it'd simplify things if I could tell in the child component and could cut my number of parameters in half.

Comment: Its based on your requirements. You can compress code by merging `addHandler` & `editHandler`. This is good, but if you would like to change to something else, you can use `Subject` or `BehaviourSubject` to talk within components

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update (v8+)

`observers` have now been moved internally to `Subject`. Thanks to @Tonio for pointing it out.

The new `Subject` implementation makes this check easier as seen [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L106) with an `observed` function

```html
<div *ngIf="editHandler.observed" (click)="...">Edit</div>
<div *ngIf="renameHandler.observed" (click)="...">Rename</div>
```

### Below v8

`EventEmitter` extends `Subject`. This means you can check if there are any `observers` attached to your `Subject`.

Try this in your HTML

```html
<div *ngIf="editHandler.observers.length > 0" (click)="...">Edit</div>
<div *ngIf="renameHandler.observers.length > 0" (click)="...">Rename</div>
```

This can also be rewritten as

```html
<div *ngIf="editHandler.observers.length" (click)="...">Edit</div>
<div *ngIf="renameHandler.observers.length" (click)="...">Rename</div>
```

As mentioned in the comments, here is how you can do it using a `hasObservers()` method

**HTML**

```html
<div *ngIf="hasObservers(editHandler)" (click)="...">Edit</div>
<div *ngIf="hasObservers(renameHandler)" (click)="...">Rename</div>
```

**component**

```js
hasObservers(eventEmitter: EventEmitter<any>): boolean {
    return eventEmitter.observers.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, although I'll probably see if I can't handle it through a "hasObservers" style method so it's a little more self documenting.

Comment: @Mordred - I have updated my answer to show the same.

Comment: That was exactly what I did, and it all works perfectly.

Comment: I was using this technique but I have this "depreacation" warning:

"Internal implementation detail, do not use directly. Will be made internal in v8."

Anyone knows how to replace this ?

Comment: Hi @Tonio, thanks for pointing that out, I've updated my answer.